# ¿Cómo agregar y quitar elementos de un div?

Tags: jquery, html

Quiero que al hacer `click` los elementos de `#categoria` no se remuevan y se agreguen en `#campoBusq`. Además que no inserte 2 veces `div` que ya se insertó.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
      jQuery(this).appendTo('#campoBusq');
    });
    
    jQuery('#campoBusq').on('click','.elemento',function() {
      jQuery(this).appendTo('#categoria');
    });

});
```

```css
 
#campoBusq {
border: 1px solid blue ;
width:45%;
float:left;
padding:5px;
height:200px;

}

#categoria {
border: 1px solid red;
width:45%;
padding:5px;
float:left;
height:200px;
}

.elemento {
border: 1px solid green;
width:90%;
margin:1%;
padding:1%;
float:left;
clear:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="campoBusq"></div>
  <div id="categoria">
    <div class="elemento">Chile</div>
    <div class="elemento">México</div>
    <div class="elemento">Perú</div>
    <div class="elemento">España</div>
    <div class="elemento">Argentina</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda, error, o aclaración que buscas?

Comment: Quiero que los elementos de categoria no se remuevan; por ejemplo: como un boton que muestra un texto y lo oculta pero el boton nunca se remueve

Comment: Edita la pregunta y aclara lo que necesitas para que no te cierren la pregunta. ;)

Comment: :-( peleo conmigo mismo por eso; que ofreces para el titulo ?

Comment: Edita la pregunta y en el contenido explicas lo que quieres realizar. En este momento dice `Como mantener el div de #categoria` y con sólo eso es difícil para nosotros entender lo que quieres.

Comment: @Gamez, así como eres capaz de escribir un comentario explicando lo que necesitas, por favor, intenta hacerlo desde el principio, cuando creas la pregunta.

Comment: gracias amigo por tu aclaracion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Puedes clonar el elemento y después agregárselo. ¿Así es como lo necesitas?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
       var e = $(this).clone();
       var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");
       if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){
         alert("Ya existe");
       }else{
         jQuery(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');
       } 
   });
    
    jQuery('#campoBusq').on('click','.elemento',function() {
       jQuery(this).remove();
    });

});
```

```css
 
#campoBusq {
border: 1px solid blue ;
width:45%;
float:left;
padding:5px;
height:200px;

}

#categoria {
border: 1px solid red;
width:45%;
padding:5px;
float:left;
height:200px;
}

.elemento {
border: 1px solid green;
width:90%;
margin:1%;
padding:1%;
float:left;
clear:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="campoBusq"></div>
  <div id="categoria">
    <div class="elemento 1" iden="1">Chile</div>
    <div class="elemento 2" iden="2">México</div>
    <div class="elemento 3" iden="3">Perú</div>
    <div class="elemento 4" iden="4">España</div>
    <div class="elemento 5" iden="5">Argentina</div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT**
Hay muchas maneras de validarlo, te recomiendo que lo hagas con attributo data, pero igual como lo dejé sirve. Agregas algo como un identificador. Antes de agregar el elemento clonado obtienes ese atributo y buscas un atributo con una clase igual a ese atributo dentro de div#campoBusqueda, así comparas si existe o no.

Comment: Bien amigo solo falta una funcion para que no inserte div que ya se insertaron

Comment: Me gustaria que en vez de clonar; que verifique si existe y si existe que lo remueva

Comment: A sus órdenes, Jefe. Deme un min :v

Comment: Estoy intentando usar indexof(); aver si funciona

Comment: Prueba con eso, porfa.

Comment: Estoy tratando porque apenas estoy conociendo las propiadades de jquery. pero poco a poco voy, la lucha es peliando

Comment: Prueba con el código que te puse. Si te sirvió y solucionó tu problema puedes poner mi respuesta como la buena para que otros compañeros que tengan problemas como los tuyos puedan utilizarla también.

Comment: Listo amigo me sirvio, me ahorraron semanas, semanas de investigacion; ahora estudiare estos codigos que desconozco.

Comment: Dentro de un rato lanzare otra pregunta con el mismo documento porque veo que se los identificastes y yo los voy a llamar desde la base de datos a cada div de categoria

Comment: Vale, estaré atento.

Comment: Cuando lo tenga escribire por aqui para avisar

Comment: Amigo me explican como trabaja este pedazo de codigo: ("."+identificador).length) --- Esta en el ejemplo

Comment: Identificador es en el ejemplo un número entre el 1 y el 5 (identificador guardar el valor del atributto 'iden' de los divs). El pedazo de código ese que mencionas le indica a jQuery que encuentre un elemento donde la clase sea alguna del 1 al 5. $("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length es igual a $("#campoBusq").find(".1").length (si identificador valiera 1). la propiedad length nos devuelve un número mayor a 0 si elemento existe. De lo contrario nos devuelve 0 o -1 no recuerdo bien xd